# Router BGP Next Hop

Tags: routing, router, ip, bgp

Why is the first Route preferred?

[image]

IS there a logical reason?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Lowest neighbor IP ("from" address). Just a tiebreaker.